# How to get SSL protocol version (php)

Tags: php, ssl

I've got a server Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) with PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u5.

I need to get a php environment variable that specifies which SSL protocol version is used between client and server (I mean TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2 etc.).

So, I will use that variable in a script to get different options using TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 etc...

That server has got OpenSSL/1.0.1t.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SSL_PROTOCOL` environment variable should have what you're looking for. It's documented in [the Apache manual for mod_ssl](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#envvars), along with other SSL variables.

Note that some hosting environments may not make this variable available. If you don't see it, you may need to add `SSLOptions +StdEnvVars` to your web server configuration, or to an `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Adding SSLOptions +StdEnvVars to my .htaccess I've got a new environment variable called REDIRECT_SSL_PROTOCOL . At the present value of that variable is TLSv1.2 . Is that the variable I'm looking for?

Comment: Yep, that's the one. The prefixed `REDIRECT_` is probably an artifact of your mod_rewrite configuration.

Comment: Updating: on Apache 2.4/PHP 7.3 the environment variable is SSL_PROTOCOL.